# sys view equivalent of INFORMATION_SCHEMA query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wanted to get a list of all cascading deletes in my database, so
I used the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` view:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE DELETE_RULE = 'CASCADE'
```

What is the equivalent of this query using the `sys` system views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE delete_referential_action = 1
```